# AngularStrap data-start-date not allowing date selection

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, date, angular-strap

I've got this angular datepicker

```
 <input type="text" bs-datepicker data-start-date="01/10/13" data-end-date="29/04/14" placeholder="Earliest date" id="BoundaryFrom" name="BoundaryFrom" ng-model="chartData.boundary.min" data-date-format="d M yyyy" />
```

(At the moment I've put in hard coded start and end dates just to test the functionality out.  Later I will put in an Angular expression)

Now, this part `data-start-date="01/10/13" data-end-date="29/04/14"` correctly only displays the dates between 1st October 2013 and 29 April 2014 in the calendar control but the problem is none of those dates is selectable.  I can still type in the textbox though.  Why are they not selectable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the the start date and the end date should be more specific, as well as the options being `data-min-date` and `data-max-date`. Your start and end date code should be `data-min-date="10/01/2013" data-max-date="04/29/2014"`. The full line will be

```
<input type="text" bs-datepicker data-min-date="10/01/2013" data-max-date="04/29/2014" placeholder="Earliest date" id="BoundaryFrom" name="BoundaryFrom" ng-model="chartData.boundary.min" data-date-format="d M yyyy" />
```

Also, I think the format of the date for that would be "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of "dd/mm/yyyy" like you originally did.

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/348c0M8Mil1EtCVhc598?p=preview) of working code. The calendar only allows selected dates between 1st October 2013 and 29 April 2014. I hope this helps!!!

edit: fixed a typo. Also, an upvote or accepted answer would be awesome :)

Comment: +1 upvoted for all the help.  If this works I will for sure mark as answer.